# How to avoid precision problems in C++ while using double and long double variables?

Tags: precision

I have a C++ code below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unsigned long long dec,len;
    long double dbl;

    while (cin >> dec)
    {
        len = log10(dec)+1;
        dbl = (long double) (dec);

        while (len--)
            dbl /= 10.0;

        dbl += 1e-9;

        printf ("%llu in int = %.20Lf in long double. :)\n",dec,dbl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I wanted to convert an integer to a floating-point number. But for some inputs it gave some precision errors. So I added `1e-9` before printing the result. But still it is showing errors for all the inputs, actually I got some extra digits in the result. Some of them are given below,

```
stdin
1 
12 
123 
1234 
12345 
123456 
1234567 
12345678 
123456789 
1234567890

stdout
1 in int = 0.10000000100000000000 in long double. :) 
12 in int = 0.12000000100000000001 in long double. :) 
123 in int = 0.12300000100000000000 in long double. :) 
1234 in int = 0.12340000100000000000 in long double. :) 
12345 in int = 0.12345000099999999999 in long double. :) 
123456 in int = 0.12345600100000000000 in long double. :) 
1234567 in int = 0.12345670100000000000 in long double. :) 
12345678 in int = 0.12345678099999999998 in long double. :) 
123456789 in int = 0.12345679000000000001 in long double. :) 
1234567890 in int = 0.12345679000000000001 in long double. :)
```

Is there any way to avoid or get rid of these errors? :)

Comment: Welcome to the wild, wonderful world of [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: What is your real goal?  What are you trying to do with those numbers where one [ULP (unit in the last place)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) makes a difference?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way around it. A floating point number is basically a fraction with a power of 2 as the denominator. This means that the only non-integers that can be represented exactly are multiples of a (negative) power of 2, i.e. a multiple of 1/2, or of 1/16, or of 1/1048576, or...

Now, 10 has two prime factors; 2 and 5. Thus 1/10 cannot be expressed as a fractional number with a power of 2 as the denominator. You will always end up with a rounding error. By repeatedly dividing by 10, you even make this slightly worse, so one "solution" would be to rather than dividing `dbl` by 10 repeatedly keeping a separate counter `multiplier`:

```
double multiplier = 1;
while (len--)
   multiplier *= 10.;

dbl /= multiplier;
```

Note that I don't say this will solve the problem, but it might make things slightly more stable. Assuming that you can represent a decimal number exactly in floating point remains wrong.

Comment: gratefully it works upto the first 20 digits after the decimal point :) ... but why you denied to tell the helpfulness of this approach?

Comment: It's just to make very clear that you do not have a correct representation, just one that is less wrong. The point is that if you truly need "exact" (decimal) representation, you should use something like base-10 fixed point mathematics, or binary-coded decimal floating point. However, this solution does provide you with the best representation of the original integer that is at all possible within the floating point system. Sometimes, that is enough.